# display tip when mouse is anywhere over line chart

Tags: dc.js

I have a composite line chart.

How can I display the respective values (date and value) when i hover on any place of the chart like below:

[image]

```
                var composechart = dc.compositeChart("#test_composed");

                composechart
                    .width(990)
                    .height(450)
                    .margins({ top: 50, right: 40, left: 50, bottom: 50 })
                    .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date(2017, 0, 1), new Date(2019, 10, 30)]))
                    .rangeChart(xChart)                 
                    .elasticY(true)                     
                    .xUnits(d3.timeMonths)  
                    .legend(dc.legend().x(80).y(20).itemHeight(13).gap(5))                      
                    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
                    .brushOn(false)

                    .compose([
                     dc.lineChart(composechart)  
                        .dimension(salesgrafikDim)                          
                        .group(salesgrafikGroup,"Sales"),                                                    
                     dc.lineChart(composechart)
                        .dimension(satisgrafikDim)
                        .colors('red')
                        .group(quantitygrafikGroup,"Quantity")                                                     
                    ])

                     xChart
                     .width(990)                    
                     .height(40)
                     .margins({top: 0, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 50})                
                     .dimension(salesgrafikDim)
                     .group(salesgrafikGroup)                                
                     .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date(2017, 0, 1), new Date(2019, 10, 30)]))                          
                     .xUnits(d3.timeMonths);

                     xChart.yAxis().ticks(0);
```

Basically want to display a tooltip like in the screenshot below, where the mouse should not need to be over a dot for it to display.

I can do it with straight D3, with svg and append and so on. But i have dimension with other charts and dataTable, so I want to use this with dc.js.

It would be much more user friendly and easy to understand if you don't have to hover over the dots to see the tip.

[image]

My chart is below :
[image]

Comment: Please try turning `.brushOn(false)` on each of the child charts. The [xyTips are not compatible with the brush](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/LineChart.html#xyTipsOn).

Comment: Hello Gordon. Did it. But xyTips only display when mouse is over this exact data point on chart for each child chart. What i want is display both their respective values when mouse is anywhere on x,y axis.

Comment: Ok. Definitely not a built in feature. You’ve got more than one line; would you want a tip to show for every line? What if the lines are really close together or crossing?

Comment: Yes. for every line i need a tip.  I edited answer and put my chart to clarify.

Comment: And if there is no point at the x value of the cursor, you want to show the nearest point?

Comment: yes exactly. it should be like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since dc.js doesn't support this directly, you're going to end up dropping down into D3 in order to implement this.

First, we need to disable the existing titles:

```
.title(() => '')
```

and hover events:

```
composite.on('pretransition', chart => {
  chart.children().forEach(
    child => child.selectAll('circle.dot')
      .on('mousemove', null)
      .on('mouseout', null)
    );
})
```

Then we can add a handler to put mouse handlers on the SVG itself

```
composite.on('postRender', chart => {
  chart.svg().on('mousemove', () => { // 2
    // find closest data point
    const x = chart.x().invert(d3.mouse(chart.svg().node())[0] - chart.margins().left),
      xs = chart.children()[0].group().all().map(kv => kv.key),
      right = d3.bisectLeft(xs, x);
    let closest = right;
    if(right >= xs.length)
      closest = right - 1;
    else if(right > 0) {
      // see if point to the left is closer
      if(x - xs[right-1] < xs[right] - x)
        closest = right - 1;
    }
    //console.log('closest', new Date(x), closest, xs[closest])
    chart.children().forEach(child => { // 3
      child.g().selectAll('circle.dot').each(function(d) {
        if(d.x === xs[closest]) {
          child._showDot(d3.select(this));
          child.g().select('text.data-tip')
            .attr('visibility', 'visible')
            .attr('x', child.x()(d.x))
            .attr('y', child.y()(d.y))
            .text(tooltip_text(d.data))
        } else
          child._hideDot(d3.select(this));
      });
    })
  })
  chart.svg().on('mouseout', () => { // 4
    chart.children().forEach(child => {
      child.selectAll('circle.dot').each(function(d) {
        child._hideDot(d3.select(this));
      });
    })
  })
  chart.children().forEach(child => child.g() // 1
    .append('text')
    .attr('class', 'data-tip')
    .attr('fill', 'black')
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'top')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'begin')
    .attr('visibility', 'hidden')
    )
});
```

I'm not going to get into the details, but this

1. adds a text element to each child chart, which will display the tip
2. listens for mousemove and finds the nearest point
3. shows the dots and text for the selected point in each child
4. hides all dots and text when the mouse leaves the chart

I ran out of time to think about this, so I didn't try to get the text positioned correctly or make it look nice.

#### linear scale

[image: linear scale]

[Linear scale fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/rL82bguk/165/).

#### time scale

[image: time scale]

[Time scale fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/sekhfp5q/38/).

As I mentioned in the comments, you're going to run into trouble with this design, if the lines get too close together. You can see this problem with the first point in this example.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. Fiddle works perfectly.  But i have a problem with my composite chart. It doesn't give any error. Simply don't display dots and tips on mouse move. Only different from your example is that dimension of mine based on date of each sales.  For x axis instead of scaleLinear I have scaleTime. That might prevent it from working  ?  .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date(2017, 0, 1), new Date(2019, 10, 30)]))

Comment: Thanks! It turns out there was a really bad bug. I fixed it and added a time scale fiddle.

Comment: It works perfectly on time scale now .. More than thank you @Gordon