# Unable to display tip when mouse is anywhere on chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to display tip when mouse is anywhere on the graph which will look like below( see India Total Cases) :

[image]

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60267074/6660373) but it gives me an error:

```
slider_chart.html:962 Uncaught TypeError: child._hideDot is not a function
    at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (slider_chart.html:962)
    at Pt.each (d3.v5.min.js:2)
    at slider_chart.html:952
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at SVGSVGElement.<anonymous> (slider_chart.html:951)
    at SVGSVGElement.<anonymous> (d3.v5.min.js:2)
```

**Line no 935-983:**

https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/241d14a27427dd89133e1b07919ee9b6

I am trying to implement it for 1st graph then will do the same for rest of the graphs but I am getting this error `not a function`. I tried searching on google but could not find any solution for it.

My 1st chart (`total_chart`) is defined under `function total_cases_chart()` `Line no. 863-983`.

Comment: That solution is for dc@4; it is calling a private member function that isn't visible in dc@3. So your real question is how to port those examples to dc@3. I don't feel like doing it right now, but it looks like you could copy `showDot()`, `hideDot()` out of the sources without too much trouble.

Comment: @Gordon That helped me. I ported to dc@4 version( I didn't know about the 4 being the latest) and customized the functions. Only thing left is to create a tooltip box. Rest implemented. I am getting struck at detailing parts most of the time. Thanks. for always helping me out

Comment: That’s great, glad you are on the latest now!